# Combining Lebedev and Gauss chebyshev quadratures

Tags: improper-integrals, surface-integrals, quadrature

My problem is that I need to compute 3D integrals, and I need to combine a Gauss-Chebyshev (for the radial part + variable substitution) and a Lebedev quadrature (for the solid angle/unit sphere surface part).

The first part is to process the quadrature points :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import norm
pi = np.pi

##########################
# Quadrature weights/points
##########################

# for radial component
Nr = 30
ii  = np.arange(1,Nr+1).reshape(-1,1) 
sin_i = np.sin(ii*pi/(Nr+1))
cos_i = np.cos(ii*pi/(Nr+1))

# Chebyshev quadrature points on [-1,1]
Mu_quadrature = (Nr+1.0-2.0*ii)/(Nr+1.0) + 2.0/pi*(1.0 + 2.0/3.0*sin_i**2)*cos_i*sin_i

# Chebyshev quadrature points on [0, +infty [
# Bragg-slater Radius for Hydrogen
rm = 0.35 # Angstrom
# variable substitution for the radial component 
R_quadrature = rm*(1+Mu_quadrature)/(1-Mu_quadrature)

# Chebyshev quadrature weights
Wr_quadrature = 16.0/3.0/(Nr+1)*sin_i**4

##########################
# Quadrature for solid angle / angular coordinates
##########################

# file containing integration points (theta/phi in deg) and associated weights
fn = 'lebedenev_quadrature.txt'
Data = np.loadtxt(fn)
ThetaPhi_quadrature = Data[:,:2]

# convert to rad
ThetaPhi_quadrature = ThetaPhi_quadrature*pi/180.0
Wangular_quadrature = Data[:,2:3]

# make a tensor product of the Quadrature points
X_spherical_int = np.concatenate([
        np.tile(R_quadrature,(len(ThetaPhi_quadrature),1)),
        np.repeat(ThetaPhi_quadrature,len(R_quadrature),axis=0)   
    ],
    axis=1
)

R_int   = X_spherical_int[:,0:1]
Theta_int = X_spherical_int[:,1:2]
Phi_int = X_spherical_int[:,2:3]

Mu_int  = (R_int - rm)/(R_int + rm)

Wint = np.concatenate([
        np.tile(Wr_quadrature,(len(Wangular_quadrature),1)),
        np.repeat(Wangular_quadrature,len(Wr_quadrature),axis=0)   
    ],
    axis=1
)
Wint = np.prod(Wint,axis=1,keepdims=True)

X_cartesian_int = np.zeros_like(X_spherical_int)
R, Theta, Phi = R_int, Theta_int, Phi_int
Mu = (R - rm)/(R + rm)
X_cartesian_int[:,0:1] = R*np.cos(Theta)*np.sin(Phi)
X_cartesian_int[:,1:2] = R*np.sin(Theta)*np.sin(Phi)
X_cartesian_int[:,2:3] = R*np.cos(Phi)
```

The file containing the Lebedev quadrature points can be found [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/sphere_lebedev_rule/sphere_lebedev_rule.html). At the bottom of the page as text files.

Then comes the tests, I tested the Chebyshev quadrature with the Gauss integral :

```
#################################
# Testing integration
#################################
def f(X):
    return np.exp(-np.sum(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)**2)

# solution
I1 = np.sqrt(pi)/2

# quadrature
I2 = np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(R_quadrature)*2.0*rm/(1-Mu_quadrature)**2,
    Wr_quadrature
)

print(f'Testing Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature with Gauss Integral :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')
```

In case, you are woundering with there is the

> 2.0*rm/(1-Mu_quadrature)**2

This is because the Chebyshev quadrature is on $\mu \in [-1,1]$, the actual integration on $r\in R⁺$ and the variable substitution is $r = r_m \frac{1+\mu}{1-\mu}$

The test of Lebedev with the surface of the unit sphere :

```
def f(Theta,Phi):
    return np.ones_like(Theta)

# solution
I1 = 4*pi #np.exp(-1)*4*pi

# quadrature
I2 = 4.0*pi*np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(ThetaPhi_quadrature[:,1:2],None),
    Wangular_quadrature
)
 
print(f'Testing Ledenev quadratude with Integral over unit sphere surface :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')
```

Now I am trying to compute the volume of a sphere, but with no good results :

```
#""" Unit Sphere
def f(X):
    R = norm(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    return np.where(R<=1,1,0)
I1 = 4/3*pi
#"""

""" Testing with Gauss integral
def f(X):
    return np.exp(-norm(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)**2)
I1 = 4*pi*np.sqrt(pi)/2
#"""

I2 = 4*pi*np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(X_cartesian_int)*2.0*rm/(1-Mu_int)**2,
    Wint
)

print(f'Testing Ledenv + Chebyshev qudrature with Integral over unit sphere volume :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')
```

The output is :

```
Testing Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature with Gauss Integral :
 I1 = 0.8862269254527579 | I2 = 0.8862570079725882 | I1-I2 = -3.0082519830276766e-05

Testing Ledenev quadratude with Integral over unit sphere surface :
 I1 = 12.566370614359172 | I2 = 12.566370614362953 | I1-I2 = -3.780087354243733e-12

Testing Ledenv + Chebyshev qudrature with Integral over unit sphere volume :
 I1 = 4.1887902047863905 | I2 = 12.623540989301834 | I1-I2 = -8.434750784515444
```

I also tried to only use spherical coordinates, but it did not work.

The full code :

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import norm
pi = np.pi

##########################
# Quadrature weights/points
##########################

# for radial component
Nr = 30
ii  = np.arange(1,Nr+1).reshape(-1,1) 
sin_i = np.sin(ii*pi/(Nr+1))
cos_i = np.cos(ii*pi/(Nr+1))

# Chebyshev quadrature points on [-1,1]
Mu_quadrature = (Nr+1.0-2.0*ii)/(Nr+1.0) + 2.0/pi*(1.0 + 2.0/3.0*sin_i**2)*cos_i*sin_i

# Chebyshev quadrature points on [0, +infty [
# Bragg-slater Radius for Hydrogen
rm = 0.35 # Angstrom
# variable substitution for the radial component 
R_quadrature = rm*(1+Mu_quadrature)/(1-Mu_quadrature)

# Chebyshev quadrature weights
Wr_quadrature = 16.0/3.0/(Nr+1)*sin_i**4

##########################
# Quadrature for solid angle / angular coordinates
##########################

# file containing integration points (theta/phi in deg) and associated weights
fn = 'lebedenev_quadrature.txt'
Data = np.loadtxt(fn)
ThetaPhi_quadrature = Data[:,:2]

# convert to rad
ThetaPhi_quadrature = ThetaPhi_quadrature*pi/180.0
Wangular_quadrature = Data[:,2:3]

# make a tensor product of the Quadrature points
X_spherical_int = np.concatenate([
        np.tile(R_quadrature,(len(ThetaPhi_quadrature),1)),
        np.repeat(ThetaPhi_quadrature,len(R_quadrature),axis=0)   
    ],
    axis=1
)

R_int   = X_spherical_int[:,0:1]
Theta_int = X_spherical_int[:,1:2]
Phi_int = X_spherical_int[:,2:3]

Mu_int  = (R_int - rm)/(R_int + rm)

Wint = np.concatenate([
        np.tile(Wr_quadrature,(len(Wangular_quadrature),1)),
        np.repeat(Wangular_quadrature,len(Wr_quadrature),axis=0)   
    ],
    axis=1
)
Wint = np.prod(Wint,axis=1,keepdims=True)

X_cartesian_int = np.zeros_like(X_spherical_int)
R, Theta, Phi = R_int, Theta_int, Phi_int
Mu = (R - rm)/(R + rm)
X_cartesian_int[:,0:1] = R*np.cos(Theta)*np.sin(Phi)
X_cartesian_int[:,1:2] = R*np.sin(Theta)*np.sin(Phi)
X_cartesian_int[:,2:3] = R*np.cos(Phi)

#################################
# Testing integration
#################################
def f(X):
    return np.exp(-np.sum(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)**2)

# solution
I1 = np.sqrt(pi)/2

# quadrature
I2 = np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(R_quadrature)*2.0*rm/(1-Mu_quadrature)**2,
    Wr_quadrature
)

print(f'Testing Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature with Gauss Integral :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')

def f(Theta,Phi):
    return np.ones_like(Theta)

# solution
I1 = 4*pi #np.exp(-1)*4*pi

# quadrature
I2 = 4.0*pi*np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(ThetaPhi_quadrature[:,1:2],None),
    Wangular_quadrature
)
 
print(f'Testing Ledenev quadratude with Integral over unit sphere surface :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')

#""" Unit Sphere
def f(X):
    R = norm(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    return np.where(R<=1,1,0)
I1 = 4/3*pi
#"""

""" Testing with Gauss integral
def f(X):
    return np.exp(-norm(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)**2)
I1 = 4*pi*np.sqrt(pi)/2
#"""

I2 = 4*pi*np.einsum(
    'ij,ij',
    f(X_cartesian_int)*2.0*rm/(1-Mu_int)**2,
    Wint
)

print(f'Testing Ledenv + Chebyshev qudrature with Integral over unit sphere volume :\n I1 = {I1} | I2 = {I2} | I1-I2 = {I1-I2}\n')
```
````

Comment: I'm probably not going to personally answer this question, but as general advice, please include the results of your tests in the question. It's entirely possible that the results will point to the problem. For example, if your estimates are off by a factor of 2, that's one kind of issue. If they're close to the right answer, but not as close as you'd expect given the density of quadrature points, that's another kind of issue.

Comment: I voted to close this question as needing details or clarity - mostly *clarity* because, having read the post, I am unsure what the question actually is.